# mariadb-client cannot connect to db throwing "RSA Encryption not supported"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, docker-compose, mysql8

I have a docker-compose with a 'db' and 'web' containers.
The db is a `mysql:8.0` image, and the web is a `python:3.9-slim`.

If I try to connect to the MySQL server inside the db container, it works. But **not if I try it inside the web container**, from where I get the following error:

```
root@c08888899ca9:/local/app# mysql -h db -u root -p123qwe
ERROR 2061 (HY000): RSA Encryption not supported - caching_sha2_password plugin was built with GnuTLS support
```

The mysql clients differ between containers:
the db client uses the community-mysql client:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.28 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

while the web container client uses a **mariadb-client**:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.34-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
```

And, the server version is:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.28    |
+-----------+
```

Any ideas on how to solve the "caching_sha2_password plugin" error

Many thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solutions are:

- Configure the database server to work [without SSL](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,683540,683541#msg-683541): delete `*.pem`, set `ssl=0` in `my.ini` or `my.cf`
- Rebuild the client with OpenSSL instead of GnuTLS (I suppose it's have an option to select SSL backend and this feature is only supported with OpenSSL.)
- Change one of containers to match the other: let them both be constructed with MySQL or MariaDB and with compartible configuration. There are plenty of different ready-made MySQL containers as well as web server containers, there shouldn't be a problem to choose ones that work together.